# destination IP mangle table

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have machine with 2 interfaces:

```
eth1 connected to internet (ip xx.xx.xx.xx)
eth0 connected to my laptop (ip yy.yy.yy.yy)
```

I add those lines to the firewall file in order to manage the bandwidth

```
iptables -t mangle -N TRAFFICSHAPING 2> /dev/null
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d ! yy.yy.yy.yy -j TRAFFICSHAPING
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d yy.yy.yy.yy --dport 3128 -j TRAFFICSHAPING
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -s yy.yy.yy.yy --sport 3128 -j TRAFFICSHAPING
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -j TRAFFICSHAPING.
```

in this way I control the bandwidth for all the website. What do I do need to do if I want to control a specific website?

For example: if the user try to download from 4shared.com he will get 400Kb/s , and get full speed for the rest.

Comment: Do you have to enforce that for all users, or is it ok if it only works for cooperative users and applications? Do you want to filter based on the URL or based on the IP address?